# How can I pass a callback as a variable to page.evaluate in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

**UPDATE** I am running in docker and using puppeteer version 1.11.0, since this is the [latest version that is supported by alpine linux](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-on-alpine). I am also running with `--no-sandbox`

Just for the sake of code organization, I'd like to do this in puppeteer...

```
async function crawler(url, evaluater) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(...)
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    const result = await page.evaluate(evaluater)
    return result

}

crawler('https://website.com', () => {
    return document.querySelectorAll(...)
})
```

But I get the following error....

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 
'querySelectorAll' of undefined
```

I assume the evaluator function is actually passed to `eval` so I would expect the below to work in that case

```
const result = await page.evaluate(evaluater.toString())
```

This doesn't work either though. There is no error message, but `undefined` is returned. If I move the function inline, the data is returned.

*Is there any way that I can provide a callback to `page.evaluate` that is not defined inline but passed in as a variable?*

Comment: The code you have works fine for me; if I add `.then(r => console.log(r))` I can see the selected objects in the console. Passing a function like that is no problem at all. "doesn't work" is a useless problem description; please clarify *how* the code fails for you.

Comment: The error is `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined`. In other words, `document` is not defined within the callback.

Comment: I have code very similar to hoangdv's, and puppeteer v1.10.0. Using `document` inside the function passed to `page.evaluate` works perfectly fine. Please edit your question so the code reproduces your problem.

Comment: I tried out the same exact code in latest puppeteer on MacOS and it worked fine. Somehow running chrome on alpine linux in a docker container causes the issue ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Your code looking fine, it is working in my environment. Your issue maybe comes from `puppeteer` version - Let remove `node_modules` and reinstall them,

Your website what you want to crawler was disabled crawler spy by some ways - Let test with another website.

This is my code, you can try it in you env:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function crawler(url, evaluator) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url)
  const result = await page.evaluate(evaluator)
  // await browser.close();
  return result

}

(async () => {
  let result = await crawler('https://google.com', () => {
    const nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));
    return nodes.map(({ innerText }) => innerText)
  });
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: I ran this code as is and received `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. It could be an issue with my puppeteer version. I am running puppeteer inside of docker on alpine linux and the latest that is supported there is version `v1.11.0`. I didn't think it was relevant but I guess it is so I will add that to my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I run my code with `node 11.12.0` and `puppeteer v1.16.0`

Comment: I'm `node v10.15.3` and `puppeteer v1.11.0`. I think I will just assume this is an issue with the old puppeteer version and work around it. Thanks